# Error using fromFile

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to use fromFile, but I get errors.  The file exist and can be opened with `sc.textFile` just fine, but if I open the same file with the same path, `formFile` gives an error.  Here is my code:

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import java.io.File
import scala.io.Source

val filename: String = "file:///data/text.txt"

// this works, no error and the file is opened
val msgRDD = sc.textFile(filename);

// errors with this line, see below.  The same file and same path
val lines = Source.fromFile(filename).getLines.toArray
```

Below is the error

> Name: java.io.FileNotFoundException
>       Message: file:/data/maildir/allen-p/inbox/1. (No such file or directory)
>       StackTrace:   at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
>         at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
>         at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
>         at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:91)
>         at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:76)
>         at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:54)
>         at $$$82b5b23cea489b2712a1db46c77e458$$$$w$processEmail(:193)

How can I solve this error with formFile?

Thanks

Comment: Hi the code worked for me. One thing why you have "." in your file name after "txt". Also msgRDD is just transformation, it won't read your file, try using msgRDD.collect() you'll get same error in case of sc.textFile also.
Use val filename: String = "/data/text.txt" for Source.fromFile. file:// is not needed there

Comment: That period is a typo, so the filename = "file:///data/text.txt"   I am trying to get the fromFile(filename) to work.  I am using it wrong?  I get errors like you see above. Can you help?

Comment: try to use below line
val lines = Source.fromFile("/data/text.txt").getLines.toArray Don't use file:// when reading from Source

Comment: Thanks that worked.

Comment: How to give you points?

Comment: great !!! I have posted the answer please accept it :)

Comment: look at your error message. the filename is `/data/maildir/allen-p/inbox/1` but in your code you are using `/data/text.txt` . Are you sure you are pasting the correct code for us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the file name format. You don't need to use `file://` for your file path when using `Source.fromFile`. Try to use following code for reading

```
val filename: String = "/data/text.txt"
val lines = Source.fromFile(filename).getLines.toArray
```